# Huge difference in Windows vs Linux lock cost found on benchmarks

Tags: c++, linux, windows, multithreading, locking

Here's the program I'm using to benchmark lock acquisition on Windows vs Linux:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 

    mutex m;

    clock_t tStart = clock();
    unsigned long long dd=0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 100000000;i++) 
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lck {m}; // acquire the mutex m
        dd++;
    }

    cout << ((double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;

    return dd;
}
```

I'm comparing g++ vs visual studio compiler.

Here are the results:
No optimization:

```
Windows: 37 seconds   
Linux: 3.3 seconds
```

With optimization (VS: release, g++: -O3)

```
Windows: 5.8 seconds
Linux:   0.07 seconds
```

I'm comparing Ubuntu VM running under windows with Windows 7, and I'm quite surprised that the difference is so huge.

Is this a valid comparison, or did I miss something crucial?

Comment: Well, normally I'd say that the Ubuntu VM is being scored unfairly because it doesn't have direct access to the hardware, but I would expect that to perform worse not better...Are you attatching the debugger with Visual Studio? That can slow the code down, even in Release mode...

Comment: I just run it without a debugger, it took 5.902 seconds to execute

Comment: No optimization comparison is meaningless. You should always compare release/optimized builds mainly because that's what you are going to use in the end. That said, I've played around with something like this a while ago and also found MS implementation of `std::mutex` pretty slow, as far as I remember `boost::mutex` was _way_ faster, so you could potentially use that as a replacement.

Comment: _Which_ VS? _Which_ GCC? There have been many, many versions of both of them.

Comment: I tried this on Win 7 Pro 64 bit, VS2013 express, Intel 2600K 3.4ghz cpu, and it takes about 4 seconds. I'm wondering if Linux is being clever and realizing that the process doesn't spawn any threads, the mutex never causes a context switch.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit gcc version 4.8.1, visual studio 2013.

Comment: @rcgldr I thought of that too. So I disassembled the file. Compiled program does call `_pthread_mutex_lock` and  `_pthread_mutex_unlock` in cycle with `add     cs:dd, 1`